# Add more parameters to function with declared parameter

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg

I want to add two variable in addFilter() function. But the problem is that this method allows only one parameter to get. How to extend it?

```
FMpeg::fromDisk('public')
        ->open('/uploads/videos/' .$video->file_name)
        ->addFilter(function($filters) {
            $filters->clip(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds($start), FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds($duration));
        })
        ->export()
        ->toDisk('public')
```

definition of code: I can't change this

```
public function addFilter(FilterInterface $filter)
    {
        $this->filters->add($filter);

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Just add it... explain what exactly you want to add and what do you want to do with them (with the variables)

Comment: What are you trying to do to add an additional parameter?

Comment: @lewis4u when I try to add my app says that function requires 1 parameter 3 given

Comment: But which function has 3 parameters...here in your code there is a function with 1 and 2 parameters, but none with 3

Comment: I have function addFilter() with 1 parameter. I want to pass to this function $start and $duration, because that variables aren't visible in this function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `use` with the function to pass those variables to the Clousure

```
FMpeg::fromDisk('public')
        ->open('/uploads/videos/' .$video->file_name)
        ->addFilter(function($filters) use($start, $duration) {
            $filters->clip(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds($start), FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds($duration));
        })
        ->export()
        ->toDisk('public')
```